# I need help in understanding the following kernel module written in C

Tags: c, linux, kernel

As an assignment I need to complete the following C code in order to produce a kernel module able to act as a memory, but from how it's written I can't understand how it works and why many variables are not used but just declared. I have already tried looking on the teaching material they gave me, and it's even more confusing, plus I can't find on the web a good site where to find documentation about these functions.

The code is the following:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

#define DEVICE_NAME             "my_device"
#define MAJOR_DEVICE_NUMBER     60
#define MINOR_DEVICE_NUMBER     0
#define BUF_LEN                 1024

static char msg[BUF_LEN];
static char *msg_ptr; // I'm pretty sure this should become msg_reading_offset
static int major;

MODULE_AUTHOR("<YOUR NAME>");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static ssize_t my_read (
    struct file *filp, char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset);
static ssize_t my_write (
    struct file *filp, const char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset);
static int my_open (struct inode *inode,
    struct file *filp);
static int my_close (struct inode *inode,
    struct file *filp);
static int __init my_init (void);
static void __exit my_cleanup (void);
static struct file_operations fops = {
    .read = my_read,
    .write = my_write,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_close,
};

// I need to implement this function
static int my_open (struct inode *inode,
   struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}
// and this function
static int my_close (struct inode *inode,
    struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t my_read (
    struct file *filp, char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
   int nc = 0;
   // if no more "valid" bytes can be read, stop
   if (*msg_reading_offset == 0) return 0;
   // no-negative values allowed
   if (length < 0)
      return -EINVAL;
   // read the whole msg, nothing more
   if (length > strlen(msg)) {
       length = strlen(msg);
   }
   nc = copy_to_user(buf, msg_reading_offset, length);
   /*
   updates the current reading offset pointer so that a
   recursive call due to not original
   full length will get a 0 (nothing to read)
   */
   msg_reading_offset += sizeof(char) * (length-nc);
   // returns the number of REAL bytes read.
   return length - nc;
}

static ssize_t my_write (
    struct file *filp, const char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
   int nc = 0;
   if (length > BUF_LEN)
      return BUF_LEN-length;
   nc = copy_from_user(msg,buf,length);
   msg_ptr = msg;
   return length - nc;
}

static int __init my_init (void)
{
   register_chrdev (MAJOR_DEVICE_NUMBER,
      DEVICE_NAME,
      &fops);

}
module_init(my_init);
static void __exit my_cleanup (void)
{
   unregister_chrdev (major, DEVICE_NAME);
}
module_exit(my_cleanup);
```

At the moment these are my biggest problems:

- Where are all the *inode, *filp variables going? Am I supposed to use them?
- How is this program even working? I know I need to compile it with a makefile I've been give, but then how am I supposed to access these functions?
- Is this supposed to be a real program executed by the kernel or is it just a collections of functions I should use in another C program?

I'm sorry if the questions may seem stupid, but I am at a loss to know how the hell I'm supposed to approach this.

Comment: Too broad. SO is no "explain the code" site.

Comment: First step is to learn what kernel modules are. That should clear up a bunch of stuff.

Comment: @Mat That's what I've been trying to do the past 2 days.

Comment: @Olaf should I just edit it or is it there such an "explain the code" site?

Comment: What book and web sites did you read about Linux kernel modules?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I've been using the material provided by my professor, but I've now given up and I've found some useful sites

Answer (score 3):

Your Q is a bit broad, but I'll try to give you some hints.

> Where are all the *inode, *filp variables going? Am I supposed to use them?

First read an example of how a typical character device is implemented, eg, [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm).

> How is this program even working? I know I need to compile it with a makefile I've been give, but then how am I supposed to access these functions?
>
> Is this supposed to be a real program executed by the kernel or is it just a collections of functions I should use in another C program?

This is NOT a normal executable program. As you are writing a kernel module, you are extending the kernel functionalities. You need to tell the kernel about that, normally via an `insmod` call. Eg.,

```
insmod chardev.ko
```

Then create the corresponding character device:

```
mknod /dev/chardev c 60 0    # 60 being your MAJOR_DEVICE_NUMBER
```

Then you can create your own program to `read` and `write` to your character device. Alternatively, you can use existing user-space tools:

```
echo "12345678" > /dev/chardev    # write to the device
```

and,

```
cat /dev/chardev    # read from the device
```